fix Foreign Key constraint in this SQLite3 database?
I'm creating a table of people, and I want to record a table of productions, with the amount each person contributed to that production. So we have a table of share splits; each production earns an amount of shares referenced by a splitid, and each split id covers a number of rows saying how many shares each person gets.
Why does the code fail when trying to add a production?
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE people ( personid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO "main"."people" ("name") VALUES ('Alice');
INSERT INTO "main"."people" ("name") VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO "main"."people" ("name") VALUES ('Carol');

CREATE TABLE sharesplits ( splitid INTEGER NOT NULL, person INTEGER NOT NULL, numshares INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(person) REFERENCES people(personid));

INSERT INTO "main"."sharesplits" ("splitid", "person", "numshares") VALUES (1, 1, 2); -- for splitid 1 Alice earns 2 shares
INSERT INTO "main"."sharesplits" ("splitid", "person", "numshares") VALUES (2, 1, 1); --\
INSERT INTO "main"."sharesplits" ("splitid", "person", "numshares") VALUES (2, 2, 1); --- for splitid 2 Alice, Bob and Carol all earn 1 share each
INSERT INTO "main"."sharesplits" ("splitid", "person", "numshares") VALUES (2, 3, 1); --/

CREATE TABLE productions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sharesearned INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(sharesearned) REFERENCES sharesplits(splitid));

INSERT INTO "main"."productions" ("id", "sharesearned") VALUES (1, 1);
-- ^ FAILS With Result: foreign key mismatch - "productions" referencing "sharesplits"

SQLite will ignore the constraints on foreign keys by default; hence PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;.

I ran your code in sqlite 3.46.0 and there were no errors.

I just ran your code in SqlLite 3.39. No error

Previous comments were before I edited it to add the missing PRAGMA statement. I just tested again myself in 3.46.0 and it fails with the same error.

See How do comment replies work? to learn to use @x to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter x per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without @ other commenters get no notification. PS There was no question in this post. PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Clearly your error will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

@Tyr I believe you're running into this: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes. The target of a foreign key constraint must be a primary key or have a unique index.

@Dogbert, I believe you are right. If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it. It's unfortunate, because I can't just put a unique key on the sharesplits table, so I would have to either remove the foreign key relation, or add another intermediate table for uses of share split. I think I'll just accept that the db doesn't explicitly know they're related, it's less messy and suits my needs well enough.

According to the documentation, the target of a foreign key must be a primary key or have a unique index on exactly those columns.
Based on your current schema, I don't think there's a simple way to fix this.
One suggestion: create a splitids table with just one primary key column and use that in both sharesplits and productions.
